# NuGet Package is Looking for Exact Version

Tags: .net-core, nuget, .net-core-3.1, jil

I have a NuGet Package called `ConfigurationManagement`.  It has a dependency on the Nuget Package called `Jil` (json parser).  The version listed is 2.15.4.

I have another package called `Logging.Client` that needs `Jil` 2.17.0.

When I look at them, the `ConfigurationManagement` package says it needs `>=` 2.15.4.  Which leads me to think that I should just be able to use 2.17.0.

But when I try to do that, I get the following runtime error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Jil.Core, Version=2.15.4.0'

I tried adding a reference directly to `Jil` 2.17.0 in the project referencing `ConfigurationManagement` and the Packages tree in Solution Explorer shows that it will use `Jil` 2.17.0 for `ConfigurationManagement`, but I still get the runtime exception.

**How can I get my `ConfigurationManagement` package to use the 2.17.0 version of `Jil`?** (Preferably without having to update the `ConfigurationManagement` package as another group owns that.)

---

**ConfigManagement.csproj** that references `ConfigurationManagement` :

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="ConfigurationManagement" Version="4.2.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Sigil" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Jil" Version="2.17.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Project File that references `Logging.Client` and the Project above:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

 <PropertyGroup>
   <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
 </PropertyGroup>

 <ItemGroup>
   <PackageReference Include="ARUPConfiguration" Version="4.2.1.5" />
   <PackageReference Include="Logging.Client" Version="6.1.0.14" />
   <PackageReference Include="Sigil" Version="5.0.0" />
   <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.Caching" Version="4.7.0" />
 </ItemGroup>

 <ItemGroup>
   <ProjectReference Include="..\Config\ConfigManagement.csproj"/>
   <ProjectReference Include="..\DataCacheInterfaces\DataCacheInterfaces.csproj" />
   <ProjectReference 
 </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Please share a csproj file.

Comment: What's your target framework?

Comment: @yaakov .net core 3.1

Comment: It looks like Jil has published a breaking change. It's not going to be an easy fix.

Comment: @yaakov - Yep.  Probably should not have been a minor version bump for this change.  (The breaking change is that there is not a `jil.core` as of version 2.16.  It does multi-targeting.)